# Write permission on SDK 33

Tags: permissions, sdk, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, android-api-33

I gave write and read permissions to the Android ManifestRequirementsOverride.txt file with maxSdkVersion="18" on Unreal Engine, but it does not write in SDK 33. It does not ask for any permissions at startup and does not save game progress. How can I fix? (UE4 27, Android SDK 33)

I added some attributes to Manifest file like requrstLegacystorage but no result